# How to disable multi touch with Android P?

Tags: android, multi-touch, android-9.0-pie

Add the following code in `theme.xml` and refer it with `android:theme` attribute on `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
<item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
```

And it works well below Android P.

> Unfortunately, it does't work on some devices running with Android 9.0.

Guys, how can I figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to override `dispatchTouchEvent` on my `Activity` as a plan B.

In fact, it works indeed. Although it may cause some bugs somehow.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return ev.getPointerCount() == 1 && super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: A problem is here that you will deactivate every multitouch. So zooming on a google maps map won't work anymore

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. But if you need to disable multitouch per view (e.g. for a recycerview) you can use `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` inside your layout. Working fine with Android P.

Comment: Yep, it seems that works well on most of the devices. But there are still fewer  exceptions (e.g. Huawei). Thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't think I understand your comment properly.  Does this solution work for all known Android devices or only for some?